# PCNTL for MAMP with php5.4.4. and OSX 10.8

Tags: php, mamp, pcntl

All of the instructions I find on the internet are for older versions of phpize, MAMP, php and OSX.

I've tried following the instructions at:

using php5.4.4 and OSX 10.8 and yet I keep getting this issue:

```
[27-Feb-2013 17:46:17 UTC] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: pcntl: Unable to initialize module
Module compiled with module API=20090626
PHP    compiled with module API=20100525
These options need to match
 in Unknown on line 0
```

My question is, how do I compile it with API=20100525, I upgraded the base php so I was using 5.4.4 phpize:

```
pcntl tjstalcup$ /usr/local/bin/phpize
Configuring for:
PHP Api Version:         20100412
Zend Module Api No:      20100525
Zend Extension Api No:   220100525
```

When I run make test I get:

```
PHP         : /usr/bin/php 
PHP_SAPI    : cli
PHP_VERSION : 5.3.15
ZEND_VERSION: 2.3.0
```

I feel like this is where the issue is, any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: I've got the same problem.  :-(  When trying to compile xdebug, my `phpize` comes out with 20090626 when it should be 20100525.

Comment: That's weird.  I don't know what I did, but mine is working now.  I just was editing my `phpize` script to show some intermediate shell variables and the next thing I knew, phpize was picking up the right versions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran into this problem when I was trying to install memcache on MAMP Pro running PHP 5.4.10 on OSX 10.8.

I resolved the problem by using the phpize located within the PHP version within MAMP so for example when compiling I used `/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.4.10/bin/phpize` with my PHP version being 5.4.10

I suggest phpize'ing it with `/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.x.x/bin/phpize` instead of the phpize located in the `/usr/local/bin/`

Also worth mentioning I ran into a few problems with the compiler so found a useful post [HERE](https://serverfault.com/questions/386392/troubles-with-memcache-so) which explains to use `MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=10.8 CFLAGS='-fgnu89-inline' LDFLAGS='-fgnu89-inline' CXXFLAGS='-fgnu89-inline' ./configure` instead of the ordinary `./configure`